# A looping/recursive way to initialise a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

So the end result is that I want to create something that is like `array[2][2][2]` or deeper e.g. `array[2][2][2][2][2]...` (they will all be uniform length of greater than 1).

So each array will have more than x long, with depth up to n

Right now I have:

```js
var array = new Array(2); //length of 2 is just an example

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = new Array(2);
}

console.log(array);
```

what I'm thinking is:

```
function (length, depth)
{
    //length determines how long each array will be (all arrays are same length)
    //depth determines are far we go into it
}
```

So this obviously my current code only initialises a two dimensional array very easily for x length. But if I want to go deeper, I'm wondering how I should go about that. Recursive seems to be a good path, but can't think of how to do that at the moment.

Comment: please add more details around your requirement

Comment: @Brijesh Changed it to a snippet, hopefully the console.log makes things a little clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try recursion:

```js
function getNestedArray(depth, len) {
  if (depth > 1) {
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      a.push(getNestedArray(depth - 1, len))
    }
    return a;
  } else {
    return new Array(len);
  }
}

console.log(getNestedArray(5, 2))
console.log(getNestedArray(3, 4))
console.log(getNestedArray(2, 4))
```

Comment: not quite what I need. I've editted my code so it's a snippet. Basically I need length of two for each part of the array. Sorry for not stating it properly

Comment: Will the length be consistent across depth?

Comment: Yes, length will be consistent across depth

Comment: you could use this with `getNestedArray(2)` then no?

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal No, as it's all arrays with length of 1. If you look at my snippet, it will be a double array inside each element of the original array, I've also editted my question to make it a little clearer.